# C# How to get method and selector from NoSuchElementException

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using C#.NET 4 and Selenium WebDriver 2.44.0.0 and chromeDriver.
When it cannot find element, Selenium throws error:

```
no such element
(Session info: chrome=38.0.2125.104)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

**But I would like to know which element is missing**. I see some articles said that it can show details like this:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"hello"}
```

Could anyone tell me how to get the method and selector from NoSuchElementException?

Here is my code

```
try
{
     for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
     {
          string className = "items-" + i;
          IWebElement t = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[class$='" + className + "'] > span"));
          t.Click();
     }
}
catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
{
     Logger.Error("Error: " + ex.Message);
     Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: You should really avoid "coding by exception". Exceptions should be something exceptional - like running out of hard drive space or a network connection failing. If you're writing code and expecting exceptions for your code to work "properly" then you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.ToString()` method of the `By` locator returns what you're asking for.

As far as I know the exception itself does not contain the information. However, it is straight forward to handle the exception and associate it with the locator function that was used in the `FindElement()` method that threw it.

For example, if the element in the 5th iteration cannot be found, the code below will produce this message

> Error: no such element
>
> Error: Unable to find element using function By.CssSelector: [class$='items-4'] > span

```
By locator;     // need to declare this outside the scope of the try block
                // so it can be accessed in the catch block
try
{
     for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
     {
          string className = "items-" + i;
          locatorFunction = By.CssSelector("[class$='" + className + "'] > span")
          IWebElement t = Driver.FindElement(locatorFunction);
          t.Click();
     }
}
catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
{
     Logger.Error("Error: " + ex.Message);
     Logger.Error("Error: Unable to find element using function " + locatorFunction.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I would like to avoid modifying current scripts. Is it possible to configure Selenium to display more details in exception message?

Comment: In addition to the message you have the option to get the StackTrace as well. What other information you looking for?

Comment: I don't think there are any configuration options for Selenium Exceptions. I've added a paragraph to my answer to make it clear that this is a way of associating the information with the exception and not extracting the information from the exception itself.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to selenium API doc for .net found [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html).
But, I don't think it will give you what you want in terms of exception tracking. Print the selector you are using instead which can help you identify the element throwing the error

Comment: thank you. I will use workaround from John O. answer.